# Complex types passing between axis2 server and Android application

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, ksoap2, complextype

I am having a very big problem!

I have a web service (running on tomcat, axis2) and an Android client (using ksoap2).
The web service has method that recieve and return complex types in array or as single object.

If I run the server under eclipse in my local PC - it works perfect :)

But

After I deploy it using the archiver then the complex type does not pass.
I also tried using tool java2wdsl - and I looked into it and found that for complex types there is an empty sequence.
Thetypes are in different file - maybe that is the problem?

Ay ideas how to solve this mistory?

Answer (score 1):

I also use Tomcat-Axis2-Android-Ksoap2 and I can pass complex objects and arrays. The wsdl in the server is automatically generated by Axis2. Whitout more information about your application will be difficult to help you.

Comment: What information you need? Did you use java2wsdl? or wsdl2java? Or using the simple archiver of Axis? Can we discuss it in mail? If you can - maybe can connect from remote and help me? yoavby2@gmail.com is my mail. Please... I really need some help.

Comment: Here is a working tutorial for complex types and arrays with ksoap2:
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html Hope it helps.